# High school social network query for friends in common

Tags: sql, mysql

This is sourced from the Stanford Coursera self study DB class SQL quizzes:

> Students at your hometown high school have decided to organize their
>   social network using databases. So far, they have collected
>   information about sixteen students in four grades, 9-12. Here's the
>   schema:
>
> ```
> Highschooler (ID, name, grade)
> ```
>
> English: There is a high school student with unique ID and a given
>   first name in a certain grade.
>
> ```
> Friend (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2.
>   Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is
>   (456, 123).
>
> ```
> Likes (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking
>   someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes
>   table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.
>
> Database
>   [here](https://class.coursera.org/db/wiki/view?page=SocialData)
>
> **Prompt:** For each student A who likes a student B where the two are not friends, find if they have a friend C in common (who can introduce
>   them!). For all such trios, return the name and grade of A, B, and C.

I would appreciate a brief code review of this working query:

```
select distinct a.name, a.grade, b.name, b.grade, c.name, c.grade
from highschooler a, highschooler b, highschooler c, likes, friend
where a.id=likes.id1
and b.id=likes.id2
and a.id=friend.id1
and b.id not in (select id2 from friend where a.id=id1)
and b.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
and a.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
```

Comment: Your request for a code review of your working query is on-topic. However, asking for an explanation of the broken query is off-topic, so I have [forked the question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052517/difference-between-social-network-queries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Generic issues

- The outline of the query should be made visible at a glance using indentation.  This `SELECT` has a `FROM` clause and a `WHERE` clause.  Within the `WHERE` clause, there are multiple `AND`ed conditions.
- It is conventional to use `ALL CAPS` for SQL keywords (though some people dislike that convention and disregard it).
- All selected columns should be given their own distinct names.  Otherwise, MySQL will automatically name them, and in this case, you'll get three columns each called `name` and `grade`.
- Use the same capitalization for table and column names as given in the question, since MySQL identifiers are [case-sensitive on some platforms](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

### Query formulation

- `SELECT DISTINCT` should be avoided wherever possible.  Deduplicating the results could hurt performance, and is a sign of a "wrong" query.  A properly formulated query based on a well designed schema and accurate data should almost never require deduplicating the results.
- The *a-b* and *b-c* friendship relationships should be symmetrical:

  $$\newcommand{rel}[2]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\underset{\mathtt{#2}}{\longleftrightarrow}}}
    \fbox{a} \rel{Friend}{ac} \fbox{c} \rel{Friend}{bc} \fbox{b}
    $$

  Therefore, I would expect two `Friend` tables included in the join on equal footing.
- In fact, **I'm not convinced that your query is correct**.  You have the condition `a.id=friend.id1`, but there is no mention of `friend.id2` at all.  Your query merely specifies that *a* is not friendless.
- It should be possible to formulate the join without so many subselects.

Here's one way to write it:

```
SELECT a.name AS a_name, a.grade AS a_grade
     , b.name AS b_name, b.grade AS b_grade
     , c.name AS c_name, c.grade AS c_grade
    FROM Highschooler a, Highschooler b, Highschooler c, Likes, Friend ac, Friend bc
    WHERE
        a.ID = Likes.ID1 AND b.ID = Likes.ID2
        AND a.ID = ac.ID1 AND ac.ID2 = bc.ID1 AND b.ID = bc.ID2
        AND a.ID = ac.ID1
        AND b.ID = ac.ID2
        AND c.ID = bc.ID2
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
                FROM Friend ab
                WHERE ab.ID1 = a.ID AND ab.ID2 = b.ID
        );
```

However, joins would be better written using the `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT a.name AS a_name, a.grade AS a_grade
     , b.name AS b_name, b.grade AS b_grade
     , c.name AS c_name, c.grade AS c_grade
    FROM Likes
        INNER JOIN Friend AS ac
            ON Likes.ID1 = ac.ID1
        INNER JOIN Friend AS bc
            ON Likes.ID2 = bc.ID2
        INNER JOIN Highschooler AS a
            ON ac.ID1 = a.ID
        INNER JOIN Highschooler AS b
            ON bc.ID2 = b.ID
        INNER JOIN Highschooler AS c
            ON ac.ID2 = c.ID
    WHERE
        ac.ID2 = bc.ID1
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
                FROM Friend AS ab
                WHERE ab.ID1 = a.ID AND ab.ID2 = b.ID
        );
```